# How to exit only when user presses return key?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my program exit only when the user presses the return key, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried getch(), but that only works for any character, and I need only the return key.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
while (getch() != '\r')
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: What is ch? A string?

Comment: Why the assignment? Its unneccessary, and why do you define it as `char[0]` o.O

Comment: You might also want to use c++ methods: `std::cin::get()` and check then for stream state too